# How to remove the site name from title in spree?

Tags: title, spree

In **Spree > Configuration** the **Site Name** is what is set in the  tag of your website. It renders in your browser’s title bar on every page of the public-facing area of the site. I want to remove the site name from titles on my website. I tried to remove it but when I click update after deleting it from text area in **Spree > Configuration** (as shown in image) it shows up again after updating.

How can I remove it without going into coding from spree admin panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You store configuration is stored inside of a `Spree::Store` model. This way you can have multiple storefronts. For example, what if you have a clothing brand that sells mens clothing and another brand that sells woman's clothing? This was the purpose behind the `Spree::Store` model; which came from the `spree_multi_store` gem.

Anywho, if you would like to update the store information, you can do it from the admin as @arv details. If you want to update it from the `rails console`:

```
store = Spree::Store.current
store.name = 'My New Store Name'
store.save
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change site name for admin panel general setting , and it is good to mention in which spree version you are getting problem to mention. check this https://guides.spreecommerce.com/user/configuring_general_settings.html

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project path as follows
`yourproject/app/views/spree/shared/_head.html.erb`
and change the title in the view directly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest turning off the configuration parameter for that as such:

in your config/initializers/spree.rb

```html
Spree.config do |config|
  ...
  config.always_put_site_name_in_title = false
end
```